# Convert String to Textbox Name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a 9 Textboxes and I want to get their values with `Val(Me.TxtBoxName.Text))`.

The Textboxes already all exists and are named. I want to build the names and access their values with

```
For i = 0 To 2
    For j = 0 To 2
        getText = "Me." & "eing_" & i & j & ".Text"
        Debug.WriteLine(Val(getText))
    Next
Next
```

(This will get me the Textbox Names eing_00, eing_01, eing_02, eing_10, eing_11, eing_12, eing_20, eing_21, eing_22)

But this does not work as getText is a String. How can I convert it so I can access the Textbox properly?

Comment: Don't use `Val`. The situations in which it is a good idea are very rare. If you want a `Double` from a `String` then use `Double.Parse` or `Convert.ToDouble` if you know the input is valid or else use `Double.TryParse` to validate and convert in one go. If the user entered "12o34" by mistake instead of "12034" then `Val` would return 12.0, which is obviously not what you want but you wouldn't know it was wrong. Only use `Val` if you specifically want to slice a number off the front of an alphanumeric `String`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You don't magically turn a `String` into an identifier.

Fortunately though, all controls have a `Name` property and you can use that property to index the `Controls` collection of the parent to get a reference to a control. When you add a control in the designer, the `Name` property is the same as the field declared to refer to the control, e.g. if you add a `Button` to a form and do this:

```vb
MessageBox.Show(Button1.Name)
```

then it will display "Button1".

So, in your case, that means that you would replace this nonsense:

```vb
getText = "Me." & "eing_" & i & j & ".Text"
```

with this:

```vb
getText = Controls($"eing_{i}{j}").Text
```

That assumes that the controls were added directly to the form. If they were added to some other container, e.g. a `Panel`, then you must use the `Controls` collection of that container, rather than that of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pay attention to the difference between numbers and strings. The `Name` property of a `Control` is a `String` but the control itself is type `Control` and the inherited type `TextBox` in this case. We can refer to an item in the `ControlsCollection` by providing a `String` which is the `Name` property of the control.

The `.TryParse` takes a `String` and checks if the string can be converted to a the Type you are parsing. In this case Double. It returns True or False and if True it assigns the converted value to the second parameter. It is important to use this because users can enter any old thing in a text box.

I wasn't sure what kind of number you were expecting so I chose `Double`. Change to a narrower type if you can. If you need to manipulate numbers with arithmetic they cannot be strings (the `Text` property is a string)

As a side note, you can do several things with a list of numbers, `Average`, `Max`, `Min`, or `Sum`.

```
Dim total = numbers.Sum
```

Turn on Option Strict to help identify type problems.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim numbers As New List(Of Double)
    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = 0 To 2
            Dim getText = "eing_" & i & j
            Dim ctrl = Controls(getText)
            Dim d As Double
            If Double.TryParse(ctrl.Text, d) Then
                numbers.Add(d)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each d In numbers
        Debug.Print(d.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Even though the problem got solved already with another answer, I tried to understand yours and I am not exactly sure what you are trying to say in the first paragraph.
I know that I cannot insert a String to call the Textbox that was the whole reason why I asked this question. Also I am not sure why you're adding numbers together.

Comment: I am not adding the numbers. `numbers` is a `List(Of Double)`, `numbers.Add()` calls the `.Add` method of `List(Of T)` which adds an element to the list.

Comment: I have edited the first paragraph of my answer. Sorry, it wasn't too clear at first. If you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: Please note that I have commented out I have edited my code here. It was incorrect before. Sorry again. `Dim getText = "eing_" & i & j`

Comment: I was wrong again! The Control class does, indeed, have a .Text property.